# Pandas groupby with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a summary of call logs.
There are 4 cases

1. There is only one call log record for a phone and it has outcome, we
   choose its values for duration, status and outcome_record
2. Multiple call logs of same phone has outcome, we choose the summary, duration and outcome_record of call log with max duration
3. There is only one call log record for a phone and it doesn't have
   outcome, we choose its values for duration and status. outcome_record will be None
4. Multiple call logs of same phone doesn't have outcome, we choose the
   summary and duration of call log with max duration.
   outcome_record will be None

What I tried is looping on the groups. But it is terribly slow when dealing with huge amount of data. I think I need to use pandas methods instead of looping. How to use pandas methods to achieve the same, with multiple conditions. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
def get_summarized_call_logs_df(df):
    data_list = []
    phone_groups = df.groupby('phone')
    unique_phones = df.phone.unique()
    for ph in unique_phones:
        row_data = {"phone": ph}
        group = phone_groups.get_group(ph)
        group_len = len(group)
        if True in group['outcome'].to_list():
            outcome = group.loc[group['outcome'] == True]
            row_data.update({"has_outcome": True})
            if outcome.phone.count() == 1:
                # Cases where there is outcome for single calls
                row_data.update({"status": outcome.status.iloc[0],
                                 "duration": outcome.duration.iloc[0],
                                 "outcome_record": outcome.id.iloc[0]})
            else:
                # Cases where there is outcome for multiple calls
                # We choose the status and duration of outcome record with maximum duration
                out_rec = outcome.loc[outcome['duration'] == outcome['duration'].max()]
                row_data.update({"status": out_rec.status.iloc[0],
                                 "duration": out_rec.duration.iloc[0],
                                 "outcome_record": out_rec.id.iloc[0]})
        else:
            row_data.update({"has_outcome": False, "outcome_record": None})
            if group_len == 1:
                # Cases where there is no outcome for single calls
                row_data.update({"status": group.status.iloc[0], "duration": group.duration.iloc[0]})
            else:
                # Cases where there is no outcome for multiple calls
                # We choose the status and duration of the record with maximum duration
                row_data.update({"status": group.loc[group['duration'] == group['duration'].max()].status.iloc[0],
                                "duration": group.loc[group['duration'] == group['duration'].max()].duration.iloc[0]})
        data_list.append(row_data)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
    return new_df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [
    {"id": 1, "phone": "123", "outcome": True, "status": "sale", "duration": 1550},
    {"id": 2, "phone": "123", "outcome": False, "status": "failed", "duration": 3},
    {"id": 3, "phone": "123", "outcome": False, "status": "no_ring", "duration": 5},
    {"id": 4, "phone": "456", "outcome": True, "status": "call_back", "duration": 550},
    {"id": 5, "phone": "456", "outcome": True, "status": "sale", "duration": 2500},
    {"id": 6, "phone": "456", "outcome": False, "status": "no_ring", "duration": 5},
    {"id": 7, "phone": "789", "outcome": False, "status": "no_pick", "duration": 4},
    {"id": 8, "phone": "741", "outcome": False, "status": "try_again", "duration": 25},
    {"id": 9, "phone": "741", "outcome": False, "status": "try_again", "duration": 10},
    {"id": 10, "phone": "741", "outcome": False, "status": "no_ring", "duration": 5},
    ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    new_df = get_summarized_call_logs_df(df)
    print(new_df)
```

It should produce an output

```
  phone  has_outcome     status  duration  outcome_record
0   123         True       sale      1550             1.0
1   456         True       sale      2500             5.0
2   789        False    no_pick         4             NaN
3   741        False  try_again        25             NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify the logic. If you sort your values mainly by 'outcome' and 'duration', you just have to drop duplicates and keep the last row of each sorted groups like this:

```
cols = ['phone', 'outcome', 'duration']
new_df = df.sort_values(cols).drop_duplicates('phone', keep='last')
print(new_df)

# Output:
   id phone  outcome     status  duration
0   1   123     True       sale      1550
4   5   456     True       sale      2500
7   8   741    False  try_again        25
6   7   789    False    no_pick         4
```

From @user10375196, to get the expected outcome:

```
new_df = new_df.rename(columns={'id': 'outcome_record', 'outcome': 'has_outcome'})
new_df.loc[new_df.has_outcome == False, "outcome_record"] = None
new_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(new_df)

# Output:
   outcome_record phone  has_outcome     status  duration
0             1.0   123         True       sale      1550
1             5.0   456         True       sale      2500
2             NaN   741        False  try_again        25
3             NaN   789        False    no_pick         4
```

Comment: Should it be `new_df = df.sort_values(cols).drop_duplicates('phone', keep='first')` instead of  `keep='last'`? I'm getting wrong values on `keep='last'` when working with real data, and correct on `keep='first'`...

Comment: Are you sure? The highest values are at the bottom of your dataframe because order is ascending by default. `first: False ---> last: True`, `first: 3 ---> last: 1500`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There were 'None' values in real data for the 'outcome' field. And I think it's giving `None` more weight than `True`, when ordered in ascending. This was leading to error in my case. I replaced the `None` with `False` for `outcome` field to fix the issue. BTW your answer is simple and faster. To get 'outcome_record' and complete the answer I used 'new_df = new_df.rename(columns={'id': 'outcome_record', 'outcome': 'has_outcome'})
    new_df.loc[test_df.has_outcome == False, "outcome_record"] = None
    new_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)'

Comment: I updated my answer with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an alternative stream processing option (no need to fit input data into memory), based on [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools):

```py
from convtools import conversion as c

# fmt: off
data = [
    {"id": 1, "phone": "123", "outcome": True, "status": "sale", "duration": 1550},
    {"id": 2, "phone": "123", "outcome": False, "status": "failed", "duration": 3},
    {"id": 3, "phone": "123", "outcome": False, "status": "no_ring", "duration": 5},
    {"id": 4, "phone": "456", "outcome": True, "status": "call_back", "duration": 550},
    {"id": 5, "phone": "456", "outcome": True, "status": "sale", "duration": 2500},
    {"id": 6, "phone": "456", "outcome": False, "status": "no_ring", "duration": 5},
    {"id": 7, "phone": "789", "outcome": False, "status": "no_pick", "duration": 4},
    {"id": 8, "phone": "741", "outcome": False, "status": "try_again", "duration": 25},
    {"id": 9, "phone": "741", "outcome": False, "status": "try_again", "duration": 10},
    {"id": 10, "phone": "741", "outcome": False, "status": "no_ring", "duration": 5},
]
# fmt: on

# you are interested in rows with max duration
max_duration_call_log = c.ReduceFuncs.MaxRow(c.item("duration"))

# you need to know whether there's been an outcome
has_outcome = c.ReduceFuncs.Count(where=c.item("outcome")) > 0

converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item("phone"))
    .aggregate(
        {
            "phone": c.item("phone"),
            "has_outcome": has_outcome,
            "status": max_duration_call_log.item("status"),
            "duration": max_duration_call_log.item("duration"),
            "outcome_record": c.if_(
                has_outcome,
                max_duration_call_log.item("id"),
                None,
            ),
        }
    )
    # this step generates and compiles ad hoc function
    .gen_converter()
)

# fmt: off
assert converter(data) == [
    {'phone': '123', 'has_outcome': True, 'status': 'sale', 'duration': 1550, 'outcome_record': 1},
    {'phone': '456', 'has_outcome': True, 'status': 'sale', 'duration': 2500, 'outcome_record': 5},
    {'phone': '789', 'has_outcome': False, 'status': 'no_pick', 'duration': 4, 'outcome_record': None},
    {'phone': '741', 'has_outcome': False, 'status': 'try_again', 'duration': 25, 'outcome_record': None},
]
# fmt: on
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet. The other answer seemed simple to me

Comment: The above is pure python and hence may be more flexible in some cases (e.g. MaxRow let's you play the the original row).

Also it doesn't need to pre-sort the data, it can work with a stream so it doesn't require the data to fit into memory.

However since it's a pure python, it lacks pandas' vectorizations and the stuff.
So, this may be a decent complement to other tools like polars/pandas.